# Compute the Fourier transform of a function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

How do you go about computing the Fourier transform of the following function: 
$(\frac{d}{dx}-x)^ke^{-x^2/2}$? 
Do we go about it using the binomial formula?

Comment: $\frac d{dx}$ and $-x$ does not seem to commute.

Comment: @KemonoChen yes, i dont think we've to compute $\frac{d}{dx}(-x)$. which is why I'm doubtful on how to approach the question. I got the question from Strichartz's book, chapter 3 question 16.

Comment: Try computing $\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} - x\right)^k e^{-x^2/2}$ for small $k$ and see if you can find a pattern to prove by induction.

Comment: The fact that $(\frac{d}{dx}-x)^ke^{-x^2/2}=0$ seems like it might possibly be useful...

Comment: @David C. Ullrich how do we know that it is equal to 0?

Comment: @Anon First semester calculus. Say $f(x)=\exp(-x^2/2)$. What is $f'(x)$?

Comment: @David: Wouldn't you need to have "+x" instead of "-x" for that to be true?

Comment: @PhoemueX Oops. Yes, that minus sign strikes again, thanks. (Although to tell you the truth it's so natural with the $+x$ that I suspect that the OP was a typo... For example, one can use $f'(x)+xf(x)$ to _calculate_ the Fourier transform of $f$: otoh I don't see how $f'-xf(x)$ has anything to do with anything...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Both plus and minus are natural and OP does not need fixing. $+$ corresponds to the annihilation operator acting on the ground state of the quantum harmonic oscillator, whereas $-$ corresponds to the adjoint, i.e., the creation operator. This is one of the simplest Schroedinger operator on $\mathbb{R}$ that one can diagonalize explicitly.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam do you have an idea on how I could possibly solve it? I thought of using the binomial formula to open up the bracket and then compute the fourier transforms of them individually but I'm getting confused with the combinations part.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam : It is interesting to me that these operator methods appeared in one of the earliest papers of Schrodinger. This ought to be a standard topic by now in Fourier Analysis now, especially considering the fact that these functions, when normalized, form an orthonormal basis of the unitary Fourier transform on $L^2$ with eigenvalues $1,i,-1,-i$. I can't understand why any Professor in Math would not want to know that the Fourier transform is diagonalizable with 4 eigenvalues! That's an interesting fact. Plus, we know the eigenfunctions from Schrodinger's ladder operators.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts: In some sense from this point of view the Hamiltonian of the harmonic oscillator $H=a^{\ast}a+\frac{1}{2}$ is more fundamental than the Fourier transform because the latter is just the corresponding unitary evolution $e^{-itH}$ at a particular value of $t$. The larger story involves Mehler's formula and also the fact that the $h_k$ give Schauder bases for Schwartz space as well as the space of temperate distributions. When I teach Fourier analysis I do all that, right after Fourier inversion and Plancherel.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam : That's fantastic, and tremendously helpful to those in Physics and Engineering. Those in Mathematics will find the subject to be rich and elegant. The subject is old enough (having originated with Schrodinger in one of his earliest papers,) that it should be included in standard treatments of Fourier Analysis. At least you're doing your job. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem with transforming this function, which is a polynomial times $e^{-x^2/2}$. For a smooth and rapidly decreasing function $f$,
\begin{align}
    &\mathscr{F}\left((\frac{d}{dx}-x)f\right) \\
   &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-is x}(\frac{d}{dx}-x)f(x)dx \\
   &= is\hat{f}(s)-i\frac{d}{ds}\hat{f}(s) \\
   &= -i \left(\frac{d}{ds}-s\right)\mathscr{F}f.
\end{align}
So,
$$
           \mathscr{F}\left((\frac{d}{dx}-x)^ke^{-x^2/2}\right)=(-i)^k(\frac{d}{ds}-s)^k\mathscr{F}e^{-x^2/2}.
$$
Because $\mathscr{F}e^{-x^2/2}=e^{-s^2/2}$, it follows that the Fourier transform of
$$
                      h_k(x)=\left(\frac{d}{dx}-x\right)^k e^{-x^2/2}
$$
is $(-i)^k h_k(s)$.

**Note:** These functions are eigenfunctions of the unitary Fourier transform on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$:
$$
                      \mathscr{F} h_k = (-i)^k h_k.
$$
These functions $\{ h_k \}_{k=0}^{\infty}$, when normalized in $L^2$ length, form an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ that diagonalizes the unitary Fourier transform. The unitary Fourier transform has spectrum $\sigma(\mathscr{F})=\{1,i,-1,-i\}$.

Comment: disintegrating by parts - love the name :P